# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No user is currently signed in

Tags: java, spring, facebook-login, java-threads

I have been try to integrate social login in my spring application. Previously I had encountered errors like no bean name facebook and connectionRepository. Once I integrated code from https://github.com/spring-social/spring-social-google-example, specially socialConfig and other files , I was able to move forward. But still I get error, `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No user is currently signed in`, which exists on `SecurityContext.java` file where the `getCurrentUser()` method throws `IllegalStateException`, Even though I have set the currentUser from the `SimpleSignInAdapter.signIn` method.
For facebook user i have used the `org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User` and set `SecurityContext.setCurrentUser(new User(userId, null, null, null, null, null));`

Error occurs from ConnectionRepository.connectionRepository while calling User user = SecurityContext.getCurrentUser(). I have printed the value and it returns null and exception is thrown. I havent used threadlocal before and having difficulties working it. Is there another alternatives for threadlocal and any other possible solution ?

My SecurityContext class is as below

```
public  final class SecurityContext  {

    private static final ThreadLocal<User> currentUser = new ThreadLocal<User>();
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityContext.class);

    public static User getCurrentUser() {
        User user = currentUser.get();
        if (user == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No user is currently signed in");
        }
        return user;
    }

    public static void setCurrentUser(User user) {
        currentUser.set(user);
    }

    public static boolean userSignedIn() {
        return currentUser.get() != null;
    }

    public static void remove() {
        currentUser.remove();
    }

}
```

The ThreadLocal currentUser is set from following class

```
public final class SimpleSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {

    private final UserCookieGenerator userCookieGenerator = new UserCookieGenerator();
    
    public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {
User user= new User(userId, null, null, null, null, null);
        SecurityContext.setCurrentUser(user);
        userCookieGenerator.addCookie(userId, request.getNativeResponse(HttpServletResponse.class));
         boolean flag = true;
            if (flag) {        
                return "/signup";
            }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Below is my connectionRepository method from socialConfig.class from where the error occurs while calling SecurityContext.getCurrentUser() which is null even thoogh the currentuser is set in above class.

```
    @Bean
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public ConnectionRepository connectionRepository() {
    User user = SecurityContext.getCurrentUser();
    ConnectionRepositorycr=usersConnectionRepository().createConnectionRepository(user.getId());
    logger.debug("cr==>"+cr);
    return cr;
}
```

Comment: If you keep it in thread local, `getCurrentUser` must be called on the **same thread** where `setCurrentUser` was previously called. If your app is web-based, the request triggering `getCurrentUser` may be handled by a different thread than the one handled sign in.

Comment: Can you suggest me any other alternatives for thread local. I am stuck with it.